# Ansible Tower / AWX - Job Execution when Instance Fails / becomes unavailable

Tags: ansible

Respected Members,
I have queries on the Ansible Tower/ AWX job execution. While a playbook is under execution. Lets assume this is a lengthy list of tasks and below are the two scenario. This is more on towards behavioral understanding, so I don't have any examples code or screenshot.

Scenario1: Instance fails during execution of playbook
Total Number of servers: 100
Instances: 1

1. Task3 has executed on 8 servers and the instance fails
2. Task3 has executed on 8 servers and the CPU / Memory has peeked

Scenario2: Instance fails during execution of playbook
Total Number of servers: 100
Instances: 3 (MultiNode Cluster)

1. Task3 has executed on 8 servers and the instance fails
2. Task3 has executed on 8 servers and the CPU / Memory has peeked

In Scenario 2, what happens in case the forks are such that the task3 is executing split across the instances capped at forks of 3. Does the job load get shifted to another instance automatically?

Best Regards

Comment: Since the question is not about programming at all, but about system design and behavior, it seems not to fit here but on other sites on stackexchange.

Comment: However, "_Does the job load get shifted to another instance automatically?_" according [Ansible Tower Instance Groups](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-tower-feature-spotlight-instance-groups-and-isolated-nodes) and [Instance Groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/instance_groups.html) and as I understand them, no.